# Change Notice: Undefined Index error into user friendly "Does Not Exist"

Tags: php, curl

I would like to return a user friendly "Client Does Not Exist" instead of Notice: Undefined Index error.

I have an IF statement to capture errors however it seems like PHP CURL does not see this as an error it is more a statement.

I am using a $_GET to get a variable from my URL:

```
$Url = $_GET['hotel'];
```

The error catchment i am using is:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$responseDataFetch = json_decode($response, true);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $responseDataFetch['name'];
}
```

I am not always going to have a correct hotel variable in my URL as this is more a lookup function.

I want to change the return from Notice: Undefined Index to "This user does not exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `isset()` check:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$responseDataFetch = json_decode($response, true);

curl_close($curl);

if ( $err ) {
  //echo cURL error
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  die();
}
if (! isset( $responseDataFetch['name'] ) ) {
  //echo error if not found
  echo "This user does not exist";
  die();
}
//echo response if found
echo $responseDataFetch['name'];
```